# RxJS combineLatest even if one of the sources is not emitting values

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I need data from two sources to combine into one `res: {data1: any, data2: any}` object, and I need to achieve this **even if one of the sources doesn't emit any values**

Here's the structure I expect:

```
xxx (
    source1,
    source2,
    (data1, data2) => ({data1: data1, data2: data2})
).subscribe(res => {
    doSomething1(res.data1)
    doSomething2(res.data2)
})
```

Is there any rxjs operators that can do this?

currently I can solve this with combination of `startWith` and `combineLatest`- I emit null value so `combineLatest` can start emitting values - any better way to solve this without `startWith(null)`?

```
combineLatest (
    source1.pipe(startWith(null)),
    source2.pipe(startWith(null)),
    (data1, data2) => ({data1: data1, data2: data2})
).subscribe(res => {
    if(res.data1) {
        doSomething1(res.data1)
    }
    if(res.data2) {
        doSomething2(res.data2)
    }
})
```

Comment: `any better way to solve this without startWith(null)?` No. That's how combineLatest works. Do you really need combineLatest?

Comment: @ritaj no what I need is to get values at least from one source if other is dead

Comment: Well using `startWith` is a normal solution for your problem.

Answer (score 6):

As @ritaj already mentioned, you seem to do it fine already, **though**:

1. I would substitute `startWith` with [**defaultIfEmpty operator**](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/defaultIfEmpty/) to proceed only if any of the observables is empty. Heres a marble diagram to compare the two approaches:

[image: startWith vs defaultIfEmpty with combineLatest operator]

* *Note that stream with `startWith` emits twice*

2. Use a unique object (or Symbol) instead of simple `null`, just in case of a source stream really emits `null`. This will ensure that we filter out only our markers, but not real results
3. Use a filter instead of `if-else` in the subscription — should look just a bit cleaner. This is a general good practice to keep `.subscribe` as thin as possible

Heres an example:

```js
const NO_VALUE = {};

const result$ = combineLatest(
  a$.pipe(  defaultIfEmpty(NO_VALUE)  ),
  b$.pipe(  defaultIfEmpty(NO_VALUE)  )
)
.pipe(filter(([a, b]) => a !== NO_VALUE || b !== NO_VALUE))
```

^ **[Run this code with a marble diagram](https://thinkrx.io/gist/421726c6d7dc3d426b6e7a7b58b1bd80)**.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject). This provides you with a stream that emits a default value when subscribed to, if no more recent value is available (in this case null).

```
const subject1 = new BehaviorSubject(null),
      subject2 = new BehaviorSubject(null);

source1.subscribe(subject1);
source2.subscribe(subject2);

combineLatest(subject1, subject2).subscribe(res => {
    if(res.data1) {
        doSomething1(res.data1)
    }
    if(res.data2) {
        doSomething2(res.data2)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

i know this an old thread. however, i recently faced the same issue and solved as @godblessstrawberry did

```
  const source1 = new Subject(),
              source2 = new Subject();
        
        const vm$ = combineLatest([
            source1.pipe(startWith([{id: 1}])),
            source2.pipe(startWith(['abc'])),
        ])
            .pipe(map(([profile, page]) => ({profile, page})));
        
        vm$.subscribe(stream => {
            console.log({stream});
        })
```